# Cannot share audio file with android app

Tags: android, audio, google-drive-api, share

So I have this app, and when you press a button, it allows you to pick a file, and share it to whatever apps that allow sharing (preferably Google Drive)

However, I am only able to select a file, and the app choose does not come up that lets me pick an app to send the file to.

Also, the file is saved in .3gpp format as well.

My code:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


     Button cameraButton;
     Button recordSoundButton;
     Button launchGallery;
     Button AudioViewer;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cameraButton); //create buttons and check for ids
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                takeAPhoto();
            }


        });

        recordSoundButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recordSoundButton);
        recordSoundButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                OpenUpRecordSound();
            }//end openRecord Sound


        });//end record sound button listener

        launchGallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PhotoViewer);
        launchGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LaunchUpAPhotoGallery();

            }


        });//end launch Gallery button listener

        AudioViewer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AudioViewer);
        AudioViewer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LaunchFileManager();


            }//end on click


        });//end audio viewer listener



     // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
            // does not behave as a button
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        } //end if

    } //end onCreate

    public void OpenUpRecordSound(){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecordASound.class));

    }//end openupRecord sound

    public void takeAPhoto(){

        //fire up the camera app on the phone
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
        sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

        // Ensure that there is a camera app on the phone!
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

        // Start an activity if it's safe
        if (isIntentSafe) {
            startActivity(i);
        }//end if

    }//end takeAPhoto

    public void LaunchUpAPhotoGallery(){

        Intent intent =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }//end Photo launcher handler thingy

    public void LaunchFileManager(){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          intent.setType("file/*");
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share the sound file"));


    }//end launch file manager



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually specify the file Uri in your intent, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(soundFile),"audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share the sound file"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String filepath ="/sdcard/sample/sample.mp3";
                        Intent intent = new Intent();  
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);   
                        intent.setType("audio/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Soundboard/Ringtones/custom_ringtone.ogg";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```